# Unable to install SQL Server Express 2014 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server Express 2014 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

But the setup routine is giving me the warning message:

> System doesn't meet the minimum requirement for installing SQL Server Express 2014.

But I checked its hardware and operating system requirements. My system requirements are the same as recommended for the installation of SQL Server Express 2014.

Can someone tell why I can't install SQL Server Express 2014?

Comment: I am surprised to learn that 2014 is supported on Windows 2008.  Even though Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: What is full version of your windows server 2008 R2? x64?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specifically state which service pack level your Server 2008 R2 is on.

SQL Server Express supports these editions of server 2008 **SP1**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Datacenter 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Enterprise 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Foundation 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Web 64-bit

So maybe you need to install a service pack.

[Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server setup routine will create multiple log files for each setup that you try. They can be found in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log
```

In the `\Log` directory, you will find a `Summary.txt` file that will give you some general information of your last setup. Consult this file for more information.

At the bottom of the `Summary.txt` file you will find a reference to a sub-directory containing specific information pertaining to your last setup. Example of line in `Summary.txt`file:

```
Rules report file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191204_144000\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Check the equivalent file in your directory for other issues with your last setup.

If no errors can be found in the System Configuration Check Report, consult the following files which reside in the `...\Setup Bootstrap\Log\[DATE]_[TIME]\` directory:

- Detail.txt
- Summary_[HOSTNAME]_[DATE]_[TIME].txt
- SQLServer_ERRORLOG_[DATE_TIME].txt

One of these files should contain information on how to resolve your issues(s).