# New Network Share For Backups - Permissions don't work until instance restart?

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions

For some time, I have known this... but when I am moving my backup storage to a new network share, I must restart the service account for SQL (sometimes the instance, if the same account is used) in order for the instance to get new permissions to the share.... otherwise, it believes it has been denied.

I assume this has to do with windows logon/logoff the same as other accounts.

Is there any way around this, is this common knowledge? I don't see people writing about it in "backup how to's" or blogs

Comment: Are you referring to Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Whoops, should of specified that.  Yes

Answer (score 0):

the way I have done this in the past is to copy all the permissions from the current location folder that you currently backup to, and set these permissions in the new location.

you actually do not need to copy `all` the permissions, only the sql server related.

this is the powershell script that I have used for that:

```
#--==============================================================
#-- list all the permissions on a folder
#--==============================================================
Get-Acl -Path "\\homer\e$\DWBackups" | Format-Table -Wrap


#--==============================================================
#-- copy all the permissions from a folder to another
#--==============================================================

$Acl = Get-Acl "\\homer\e$\TS-SQLBackups"
Set-Acl "\\homer\e$\DWBackups" $Acl


#--==============================================================
#-- list all the permissions on a folder
#--==============================================================
Get-Acl -Path "\\homer\e$\DWBackups" | Format-Table -Wrap
```

To check where your backups are currently going to:

these are the default folders:

```
select 
    InstanceDefaultDataPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath'),
    InstanceDefaultLogPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultLogPath')
```

But where the backups have been gone to:

```
    -- checking backups -- shows the number of days since last full backup
    -- marcello miorelli
    -- 25-june-2014

    --04-Aug-2014- added the Backup Size
    --07-Mar-2016- added the backup location and Duration

    declare @backup_type CHAR(1) = 'D' --'D' full, 'L' log

    ;with Radhe as (
        SELECT  @@Servername as [Server_Name],
        B.name as Database_Name, 
        ISNULL(STR(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GetDate(), 
                   MAX(Backup_finish_date)))), 'NEVER') as DaysSinceLastBackup,
        ISNULL(Convert(char(11), MAX(backup_finish_date), 113)
        + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(backup_finish_date),108), 'NEVER') 
        as LastBackupDate
         
        ,BackupSize_GB=CAST(COALESCE(MAX(A.BACKUP_SIZE),
                       0)/1024.00/1024.00/1024.00   AS NUMERIC(18,2))
        ,BackupSize_MB=CAST(COALESCE(MAX(A.BACKUP_SIZE),
                        0)/1024.00/1024.00 AS NUMERIC(18,2))
        ,media_set_id = MAX(A.media_set_id)
        ,[AVG Backup Duration]= AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, 
                     A.backup_start_date, A.backup_finish_date) AS int))
        ,[Longest Backup Duration]= MAX(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, 
                     A.backup_start_date, A.backup_finish_date) AS int))
        ,A.type
        FROM sys.databases B 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset A 
                     ON A.database_name = B.name 
                    AND A.is_copy_only = 0
                    AND (@backup_type IS NULL OR A.type = @backup_type  )

        GROUP BY B.Name, A.type

    )

     SELECT r.[Server_Name]
           ,r.Database_Name
           ,[Backup Type] = r.type 
           ,r.DaysSinceLastBackup
           ,r.LastBackupDate
           ,r.BackupSize_GB
           ,r.BackupSize_MB
           ,F.physical_device_name
           ,r.[AVG Backup Duration]
           ,r.[Longest Backup Duration]

       FROM Radhe r

        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily F
                     ON R.media_set_id = F.media_set_id
```

After you grant the [relevant permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86077/22336) to your new backup folder and change it in your jobs, if sql server can read and write to that folder then  you should not need to restart your services.

However if you do you will need to do in in a controlled way, using the
[sql server management console](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254788/22336)

[image]

I hope that it does not come to that, but I had in the past some illogical behaviour on some servers and I had to plan a restart of the service - I could though, postpone it to my next [patching](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269825/22336).

Specially when [virtual machines are involved](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219226/22336).